# How to create .wav file from Uint8Array in React native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, audio, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hello as the title says i made an app that works with a BLE device which sends me data in Uint8Array format. I need to turn this data to a wav file. Is there any way to do this?